# Find metatags in body with javascript in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, mozilla, meta-tags, microdata

How do i find metatags in the body section in Mozilla Firefox?

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head profile="http://microformats.org/profile/hcalendar"></head>
    <body>
    <div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Event">
        <a href="http://www.example.com/events/spinaltap" itemprop="url" ><span itemprop="summary">Spinal Tap</span></a>
        <img itemprop="photo" src="spinal_tap.jpg" />
        <span itemprop="description">After their highly-publicized search for a new drummer,Spinal Tap kicks off their latest comeback tour with a SanFrancisco show.</span>
        When:
        <time itemprop="startDate" datetime="2015-10-15T19:00-08:00">Oct 15, 7:00PM</time>—
        <time itemprop="endDate" datetime="2015-10-15T19:00-08:00">Oct 15, 9:00PM</time>
        Where:
        <span itemprop="location" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/?Organization">
            <span itemprop="name">Warfield Theatre</span>
            <span itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Address">
                <span itemprop="street-address">982 Market St</span>, 
                <span itemprop="locality">San Francisco</span>, 
                <span itemprop="region">CA</span>
            </span>
            <span itemprop="geo" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/?Geo">
                <meta itemprop="latitude" content="35.774929"/>
                <meta itemprop="longitude" content="-122.419416"/>
            </span>
        </span>
        Category: <span itemprop="eventType">Concert</span> 
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It seems like firefox is moving the meta tags to the head making them unreachable as a child element of itemprop="geo". Is there a better way than getting the lat/lng meta tags by tag name and then puzzle them together with the itemtype="Event"?

Comment: Why are there meta tags in the middle of your document in the first place?

Comment: In HTML5, you can use the <meta> element anywhere. In this example it's annotating invisible data.

Comment: In that case your document will only work in HTML5 browsers, so you'll have to wait for Firefox 4.

Answer (score 0):

If I read [Bug 591467 "Implement HTML Microdata API"](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=591467) and [the release notes of Firefox 16.0](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/16.0/releasenotes/buglist.html) this should be supported as of Firefox 16.